# clang-format: PointerAlignment in C++14 lambda function arguments with generalized capture

Tags: c++, clang-format

Consider the following `clang-format`ted function:

```
template <typename K>
void zxcv(int a, K&& k) {
    return [ a, k{std::move(k)} ](C::c & x) mutable { return a * k(x); };
    //                                ^ oh no an extra space
}
```

It seems `clang-format` has erroneously treated the operator `&` in `C::c & x` as a binary operator instead of the unary `&`. As such, it has an extra space on the left of it.

However, when `k` is captured by value instead of by move, then the `&` is left-aligned as desired, and there are no extra spaces in square brackets:

```
template <typename K>
void zxcv(int a, K&& k) {
    return [a, k](C::c& x) mutable { return a * k(x); };
    //                ^ hooray left aligned as desired
}
```

I'm using:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)

$ cat ~/.clang-format
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 4
Language: Cpp
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
```

As I understand, initialized lambda captures should be well-supported in Clang since [version 3.4](http://releases.llvm.org/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#id1).

How should I get `clang-format` to left-align my ampersand consistently?

Comment: It appears to be working file with the latest version 7.0.0

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in [rC313622](https://reviews.llvm.org/rC313622).